# Flexbox layout reduces my buttons in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-flexboxlayout

I want to make a list with buttons using flexbox layout. If I use recyclerview and button with icon, the text does not fit in the button.

**My recyclerview layout:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/category_button"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/category_item_color"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="categoryText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="14dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/category_item_icon"
        app:iconGravity="end"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My layout manager:

```kotlin
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
layoutManager.apply {
    flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
    flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj1ib.jpg)

I tried to remove the icon from the button, after that everything worked, but I would like the button with the icon. Also, If I remove the `singleLine` param, the text in the button will move to the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the solution to your problem but an alternate way to use `cardView` as a parent and inside one `textView` and one `imageView`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="categoryText"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/category_item_icon"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```